# Boundary lines for A7 flash cards

Tags: flashcards

I am trying to make a template for A7 flash cards on A4 papers. I found a code similar to this that uses `pgfpagesuselayout`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\pgfpagesuselayout{8 on 1}[a4paper]
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{right=10cm,left=1cm} 
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{9cm}


\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1, ..., 8}{something!\newpage}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

The command `\usepackage{showframe}` displays the text, margin, header and foot boxes in addiction to the boundary lines between the flashcards.

I want to remove these boxes and just keep the boundary lines. Is that possible? is there an option for the `showframe` command that allows that? or is there another command that does just that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just grab the page boundary lines from [`showframe`](//ctan.org/pkg/showframe)'s [code](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/eso-pic/showframe.sty):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paper=a4paper,
  landscape,
  right=10cm,
  left=1cm,
  marginparwidth=9cm
}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\pgfpagesuselayout{8 on 1}[a4paper]
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \framebox(\paperwidth,\paperheight){}% From showframe.sty
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1, ..., 8}{something!\newpage}

\end{document}
```